# how can assign a jQuery value to a variable in a ftl file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, freemarker

I am new to jQuery and ftl. The process I'm trying to achieve is to assign a checkbox value to a ftl variable. In my example the variable `selectedValues` contains the necessary value which is to be copied into an ftl variable. Passing jQuery values to an ftl variable is possible.

Here is the example code I tried with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
var selectedValues="";
$checkedCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[name=numbers]:checked");
$checkedCheckboxes.each(function () {
selectedValues +=  $(this).val() +",";
});
alert(selectedValues);
});
</script>

    <#assign checkboxvalue=" ? "/>
```

Comment: It appears you've got a `<script>` inside your `<script>` - is that  a an error in your example?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, I'm affraid. Freemarker templates are evaluated on the Server side. Java Script is evaluated on the client side.